# Why is the app stopping because of app data?

Tags: java, android

When I install the app for the first time it works and everything is fine but when I try to open it the second time the app stops, this problem appears on Android 6.

And if I delete the app's data and reopen it it works, but I can't every time I want to open the app to delete its data and then open it.

Knowing that the size of the application data is very small, about 3 megabytes

So please solve this problem, or if the application data can be deleted automatically after exiting it.

This is the problem report:

```
  2022-10-15 21:05:55.389 32404-32404/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.my.app, PID: 32404
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.app/com.my.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.rif3i.alashaeatliashiratalsaaea.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:97)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:843)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:843)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170) 
        at com.rif3i.alashaeatliashiratalsaaea.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:97) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1001) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:843) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1001) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:843) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170) 
        at com.rif3i.alashaeatliashiratalsaaea.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:97) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 756236 byte allocation with 275456 free bytes and 269KB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:856)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:675)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:2228)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4215)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4089)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3939)
        at android.content.res
```

Comment: You have a substantial memory leak. Use LeakCanary or the heap analysis tools in Android Studio to try to determine where your memory leak is coming from.

Comment: I used it and the leaks appeared but I don't know how to solve it, can you help me please

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging.

Memory leake probably happens in the listview when you load the data.
How much data are you uploading?